# problem configuring traefik's ForwardAuth middleware

Tags: traefik

I have few containers, brought up with docker-compose and I want to perform authentication on of the containers.
Below the piece that I assume should do that, but it doesn't go to the authentication-backend-nginx-private, directly lands on the mds-backend-nginx-private. I'm out of idea, what could be wrong about the config...

it works if authforward configured globally: in toml file under entrypoint section, but I want it to be per particular container..

````
  mds-backend-nginx-private:
    <<: *nginx-common
    ports:
      - 8186:80
    networks:
      - cloud_private
      - mds-backend
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - NGINX_SERVER_NAME=mds-backend-nginx-private
      - WEBSITE_PROXY_NAME=mds-backend-web-private
      - WEBSITE_PROXY_PORT=8000
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.authf.ForwardAuth.Address=http://authentication-backend-nginx-private/api/v1/gateway/account?with_credentials=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=cloud_private"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mds-backend.middlewares=authf"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix: /api/v1/mds/"```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you are trying to use "middleware feature" with old traefik version.

Works in the toml file because you are using the "forward feature" present in old versions.

Check traefik tag image is equal or greater than 2.0

https://hub.docker.com/_/traefik